# Cannot capture click event on Bootstrap accordian

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap to bind data to a table then trying to catch a accordion  show event. My plan would then be to get the div id to call an ajax call to get more information on the item

so far I had no luck with this my table is built like this

```
<table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr data-bind='foreach: headers'>
                                            <td data-bind='click: $parent.sort, text: title'></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody data-bind='foreach: packages'>
                                     <tr data-toggle="collapse" class="accordion-toggle" data-bind="attr: {'data-target': '#collapse-' + msg_id }">
                                            <td><button class='btn btn-success btn-6 btn-6g'
                                                    data-bind='text: msg_id'></button></td>
                                            <td data-bind='text: subject'></td>
                                            <td data-bind='text: sender_addr'></td>
                                            <td data-bind='date: created'></td>
                                            <td></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td colspan="5" class="hiddenRow">
                                                <div  class="accordian-body collapse"  data-bind="attr: { id: 'collapse-' + msg_id }">
                                            opened
                                            </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

I'm trying to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  ko.applyBindings(new PackagesViewModel()); 

  $(document).ready(function() {
         $('div').on('show.bs.collapsing', function (e) {
             alert("Event fired on " + e.currentTarget.id);
            });
    });
```

});

to catch the event. My view model is built from an ajax request when the page loads.  Any help would be great.

Comment: Sorry forgot to say the event fire fine and the accordion shows  as expected.

Comment: I'm not seeing an accordion in your markup....

Comment: I'm coping an example on jsFiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/whytheday/QLfMU/. I have added the jquery and it works and captures the elements id which I need. But no joy on my example.

Comment: So are you still having a problem?

Comment: Yes it's not being picked up. Is this because it's being set before the Ajax call to build the table data?

Comment: When I open your Fiddle and pop in your jQuery, it appears to fire the alert just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ujvqtcqp/

Comment: Ok I'm getting somewhere in my code I added a button which will attach the event

Comment: I can get the fiddle to work but not my site. I have got some where though as the table is created after the page load. Is this to do with the Bindings. Now if i add a button to the page to apply the jQuery show.bs.collapse function it works. My new question is can I apply this on the binding through the bata bind event

Comment: Either update your current question, or close this one and ask a new one.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found out why it was not working like the Fiddle. The jquery was trying to bind the event to a table which was not yet created. It was waiting for an ajax call and then the knockout viewmodel to build the table. When that had all happen I added a button to run the jQuery event binding again, this worked and I caught the show event on the accordion. So my solution was to move the jquery event finder into my java script after the ajax request. I actually put it in the response of the AJAX request. I can now catch the event.